# how to check for a value in excel and populate column based on it

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have the following query :

My input table is

[image]

Basically I want to lookup columns for each ID.
Value3>Value2>Value1

If value3 and value column has data then ouput should show ID having value3

If value3 has data  present then populate output as Value3 , if value2 and value3 have data , then also it should populate value3

Output:

[image]

Is there formula I can write to retrieve this value?

Comment: Is your test based on the amounts in the value columns or only the presence of an amount in the column?  For your output table, what you want is the column heading, not the value?

Comment: only presence of value in the column. Amount has no significance

Answer (score 1):

If it is just three value columns, a simple way to do it would be IF tests.  Say the table you show starts in A1 (A1="ID" heading).  The formula for the first output value would be:

```
    =IF(ISBLANK(D2),IF(ISBLANK(C2),$B$1,$C$1),$D$1)
```

Copy that down the output column.  (This assumes every row in the data table is represented by a row in the output table and both have the ID column in the same order.)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a more general solution.  I’ll assume that you have five “value” columns (`B` through `F`)
and you want the result in Column `G`.  Type this formula into cell `G2`:

```
=OFFSET($B$1, 0, MAX(COLUMN(B2:F2)*NOT(ISBLANK(B2:F2)))-2)
```

and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  That makes it an “array formula”;
it will show up in the formula bar with braces (`{`…`}`) around it. 
Now drag it down as many rows as you want:

[image: demo spreadsheet]

- `ISBLANK()` checks whether a cell is blank (`TRUE` if it is, `FALSE` if it isn’t).
- `NOT(…)` inverts the logic; now we have `TRUE` if the cell has (non-blank) data
  and `FALSE` if it doesn’t have data. 
  It turns out the `TRUE` is actually the value `1` and `FALSE` is actually `0`.
- `COLUMN(B2:F2)*(the above)` takes the column number of each cell in the range
  and multiplies it by 1 if the cell has data and 0 if it doesn’t. 
  This results in the column number (×1) if the cell has data,
  and 0 (column number × 0) if it doesn’t. 
  For example, for Row 3, this is {2,0,4,0,0},
  because the second (`B`) and fourth (`D`) columns have data.
- `MAX(…)` picks the largest of these; i.e., the number of the right-most column where there is data.
- `=OFFSET($B$1, 0, (the above)-2)` finds the cell that is 0 rows below
  and `MAX(COLUMN(B2:F2)*NOT(ISBLANK(B2:F2)))-2` columns to the right of cell `B1`. 
  We subtract 2 from the column number because `B1` is in column 2,
  so, when `MAX(COLUMN(B2:F2)*NOT(ISBLANK(B2:F2)))` evaluates to 2 (as it does on Row 2),
  we want to go 0 columns to the right of cell `B1`.